# Angular Image Magnify on hover

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript

I haven't been able to find any npm modules or packages that work. I'd really appreciate the help. I have tried magnify.js and ngx-imagezoom and both didn't work.

```
<img id="sample-watch" src="https://i.imgur.com/jnRTmfe.jpg" alt="Sample image" class="zoom" data-magnify-src="https://i.imgur.com/z9yzdPO.jpg">

  var watch:any = document.getElementById("sample-watch");
watch.magnify({
  afterLoad: function() {
    console.log('Magnification powers activated!');
  }
});
```

Console says magnify is not a function. 
I am using this project - https://github.com/thdoan/magnify

Comment: Welcome to SO, Please add some code or url, So someone has quickly fixed your issue.

Comment: Edited @jaydeeppatel